# Abstract Algebra: Determine if the order of a group is divisible by $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose you have a group, $G$, and two subgroups of $G$, $H$ and $K$. If $|H| = |K| =p$ for $p$ being some prime, but $H$ does not equal $K$, then the intersection of $H$ and $K$ will only contain the identity. In general, does $p^2$ divide $|G|$ and how would you justify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Look at the symmetric group $S_3$, with $p=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* true in a $p$-group though or, more general, if $H$ and $K$ are contained in the *same* Sylow $p$-subgroup. Then use the formula $|HK|=\frac{|H| \cdot |K|}{|H \cap K|}$, which yields that the *set* $HK$ has $p^2$ elements. But since $G$ is a $p$-group, it means that $p^2$ divides $|G|$. The same argument applies to the other premise, since the order of a Sylow $p$-subgroup divides the order of the group it lives in.